# Unknown Metric - OtherTransaction Error in NewRelic API Query

Tags: api, rest, newrelic

I've been following [NewRelic's guide to retrieve average Application Error rate](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apm/apis/api-v2-examples/application-error-rate-example-api-v2), but am running into a strange issue.

When I try to retrieve the 'OtherTransaction call count', I get the following error response:

```
{"error":{"title":"Unknown metric(s): OtherTransaction/all"}}
```

Has anyone else run across this? Is it something I could ignore during the average error rate calculation (and just return 0 in erroneous retrievals)?

Comment: Though the error message sent me in a slightly different direction, the final resolution to this issue was a different date formatting during the initial request.
The appropriate format is YYYY-MM-DD joined by a 'T' for time then HH:mm:ss followed by an offset (since the HH:mm:ss is in UTC). For instance: 2015-05-01T16:23:00+00:00

Answer (score 1):

Though the error message sent me in a slightly different direction, the final resolution to this issue was a different date formatting during the initial request. The appropriate format is YYYY-MM-DD joined by a 'T' for time then HH:mm:ss followed by an offset (since the HH:mm:ss is in UTC). For instance: 2015-05-01T16:23:00+00:00 –

Comment: Keep in mind that the offset (what follows the + in the time) is only for input. The API will only output times in UTC.